# How to ping IOS Devices to see if they are online

Tags: ping, ios, reply, status

Is it possible to ping an IOS device (Ipad or Iphone) from the command prompt? When I ping them from the command prompt (the only option by the way) I get a timed out response, unlike if I ping a windows computer. Is there a way to use the mac address or something? Thanks everyone!

Comment: Are the devices on the same network?  For example, if the device you are pinging from is hard wired and the iPad is on WiFi, there might be something in place to not allow communication between wired and wireless devices.  As long as all of your devices are connected to the same network subnet, you should be able to ping an iPad or any Apple device connected to that network.  Do you see any entries in the arp table on the machine you are pinging from?

Comment: Yes they are. Here is a video of what Im talking about: http://youtu.be/4rum4LPfYb8?hd=1

Comment: iPads and iPhones do not reply...

Comment: Wow, I see what you are saying.  The message you are getting is a “network unreachable” from what I can see.   Very strange considering you are able to ping that printer which is also on WiFi.

Comment: Could you post the results of tracert (ip address of iPad) and then do another tracert to a working device?

Comment: Also post the output of arp -a

Comment: Also are the iPads getting their IP address from dhcp or are you setting the IP address/gateway/subnet mask manually?

Comment: And no you can’t ping a MAC address.  Mac addresses exist at the network layer below where ip addresses are.  If you can successfully ping an IP address on your local network, the MAC address will display in your computers arp cache (a mapping of ip addresses to Mac addresses that your computer keeps track of), but as far as I am aware you cannot directly ping a layer 2 MAC address.

Comment: Heres the result of tracert: [Link](https://s19.postimg.org/620d0udcj/nusiness_back.png) and here is the result of arp: [Link](https://s19.postimg.org/98uwkj2yb/nusiness_back.png)

Comment: Has anyone else noticed this type of thing? Or could it have to do with my router? I don't know if you say the tracert and arp @Richie086